Embedded kernel hit OOM. It's a storage offload card running storage software. Need RCA fro OOM with below logs
   Apr  4 07:24:04 captain user.warn kernel: ncd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x200da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0 
...
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: active_anon:16415 inactive_anon:108 isolated_anon:0
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel:  active_file:0 inactive_file:17 isolated_file:0
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel:  unevictable:48219 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel:  free:7600 slab_reclaimable:1089 slab_unreclaimable:6962
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel:  mapped:2167 shmem:193 pagetables:186 bounce:0
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel:  free_cma:0
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: DMA32 free:2260kB min:48kB low:60kB high:72kB active_anon:32kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:23904kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:32664kB managed:996kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB wr
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 554 554
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: Normal free:28192kB min:28172kB low:35212kB high:42256kB active_anon:65628kB inactive_anon:432kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:68kB unevictable:168972kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:654332kB managed:568044kB ml
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: DMA32: 1*4kB (M) 8*8kB (UM) 11*16kB (UM) 11*32kB (UM) 6*64kB (UM) 4*128kB (UM) 3*256kB (M) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB 0*8192kB 0*16384kB 0*32768kB = 2260kB
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: Normal: 275*4kB (UEM) 160*8kB (UEM) 117*16kB (UEM) 44*32kB (UEM) 19*64kB (UEM) 19*128kB (UM) 11*256kB (UM) 4*512kB (M) 5*1024kB (UM) 1*2048kB (R) 0*4096kB 1*8192kB (R) 0*16384kB 0*32768kB = 29532kB
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=1 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: 48432 total pagecache pages
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: Total swap = 0kB
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: 321536 pages RAM
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: 172881 pages reserved
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: 4250 pages shared
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.warn kernel: 137397 pages non-shared
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1042]     0  1042     1202       84       6        0             0 klogd
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1058]     0  1058     1771      312       7        0         -1000 sshd
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1064]     0  1064     1202       86       5        0             0 syslogd
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1124]     0  1124     1202       85       6        0             0 ntpd
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1143]     0  1143    30746    12286      28        0             0 scd
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1146]     0  1146      296       81       4        0             0 nq_ach
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1151]     0  1151      296       96       4        0             0 dst
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1185]     0  1185      312       71       4        0             0 nvmeoe
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1190]     0  1190      312       71       4        0             0 nvmeoe
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1222]     0  1222      328       71       4        0             0 btp
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1226]     0  1226      328       73       4        0             0 btp
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1242]     0  1242      328       16       4        0             0 nq_cmpl
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1257]     0  1257      296       15       4        0             0 nq_iom
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1260]     0  1260      623      139       4        0             0 ldfs
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1262]     0  1262      623      139       4        0             0 ldfs
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1264]     0  1264      623      139       4        0             0 ldfs
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1266]     0  1266      623      139       4        0             0 ldfs
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1274]     0  1274      328       72       4        0             0 mariner
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1275]     0  1275      328       72       4        0             0 mariner
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1276]     0  1276      328       72       4        0             0 mariner
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1277]     0  1277      328       72       4        0             0 mariner
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1303]     0  1303    42366     4522      55        0             0 ncd
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1305]     0  1305     1202      174       5        0             0 crond
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.info kernel: [ 1306]     0  1306     1218      225       6        0             0 sh
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.err kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 1143 (scd) score 80 or sacrifice child
    Apr  4 07:24:05 captain user.err kernel: Killed process 1143 (scd) total-vm:122984kB, anon-rss:47992kB, file-rss:1152kB

Kernel logged these messages. What can be the reason? Can there be a memory leak? I am not able to understand what to look for in this.
DRAM             : 8 GB
DDR clock        : 1200 MHz
Data rate        : 2400 MHz

I understand
Normal free:28192kB: Only about 28 MB of free memory is available, which is very low.
